# Jupiter vs iPython => the big split at the 4.0 version and pyspark notebook config

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, pyspark, jupyter

Can we have an clear explanation of what happened between the monolytic iPython 3.x and the splited and bundled Jupyter  4.0.4 + iPython 4.0.0

- What went to the "language agnostic" Jupyter 4.0.4?
- What stayed in iPython 4.0.0?

I would specifically would like to know, if I want to add a pyspark kernel kernel.json:

- what configuration(s) should be done in .jupyter
- what configuration(s) should be done in .ipython

If I'm not clear, please do edit my question!

Thanks very much.

Comment: I think this is might better to address on Jupyter / IPython specific forum as this seems to be a very broad question and does not demonstrate any specific, related, source code.

Comment: It does require code in the answer: an example of configuration file for ipython_configuration.py, ipython_kernel_configuration.py and the json file kernel.json.

Comment: If you want to add a new kernel, you would just deal with Jupyter. IPython is a kernel for Python code. However, we're hoping that with tools like [findspark](https://github.com/minrk/findspark), a separate kernel for pyspark won't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Jupyter blog](https://blog.jupyter.org/2015/04/15/the-big-split/), April 15, 2015:

> ## The Big Split™
>
> 15 APRIL 2015
>
> IPython has [grown a great deal](http://blog.fperez.org/2012/01/ipython-notebook-historical.html) over the years. As of 3.0, IPython includes:
>
> - an interactive shell
> - a REPL protocol
> - a notebook document fromat
> - a notebook document conversion tool
> - a web-based notebook authoring tool
> - tools for building interactive UI (widgets)
> - interactive parallel Python based on the above REPL protocol

And from [IPython's homepage](http://ipython.org):

> As of IPython 4.0, the language-agnostic parts of the project: the notebook format, message protocol, qtconsole, notebook web application, etc. have moved to new projects under the name Jupyter. IPython itself is focused on interactive Python, part of which is providing a Python kernel for Jupyter.

Comment: I've obviously read this before posting my question and it still doesn't tell me what to put in in which configuration file.

Comment: So did you ever find the answer to that question? (It's one year old as of yesterday.)

Comment: These blog posts from 2016 may help: https://wegetsignal.wordpress.com/2016/03/24/setup-to-run-jupyter-notebook-with-pyspark/ + http://www.prcconsulting.net/2016/05/expand-machine-learning-tools-configure-jupyteripython-notebook-for-pyspark-1-6-1/